# Como listar o nome do arquivo do diretório ListBox Delphi

Tags: delphi

Como realizar a listagem de apenas o nomes dos arquivos no `ListBox` que estão localizados em uma pasta no sistema operacional, sendo que tenho que fazer operações como: excluir e salvar.

Mas, como fazer se no `ListBox` ele lista todo o diretório?
Meu Listar:

```
procedure TfrmUpDoc.ListarArquivos(Diretorio: string);
var
  F: TSearchRec;
  Ret: Integer;
begin
  Ret := FindFirst(Diretorio+'\*.*', faAnyFile, F);
  try
    while Ret = 0 do
    begin
      if not TemAtributo(F.Attr, faDirectory) then
      begin
        ListBox2.Items.Add(Diretorio+'\'+F.Name);
      end;
      Ret := FindNext(F);
    end;
  finally
    begin
      FindClose(F);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Meu Excluir:

```
procedure TfrmUpDoc.btnExcluirClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ListBox2.ItemIndex <> -1 then
  begin
    if Application.Messagebox('Confirma Exclusão deste Documento... ?','Confirmação', MB_YESNO + MB_ICONQUESTION) = mrYes then
    begin
      DeleteFile(ListBox2.Items[ListBox2.ItemIndex]);
      ListBox2.Items.delete(ListBox2.ItemIndex);
      ListBox2.update;
      AtualizaListBox;
    end;
  end
  else
    ShowMessage('Favor selecionar documento para excluir !');
end;
```

Comment: A intenção é, listar no `ListBox` apenas o nome do arquivo que for listado, e a manipulação ser pelo diretório do arquivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver pessoal:
Na procedure;
Alterei essa linha `ListBox2.Items.Add(Diretorio+'\'+F.Name);`
Para essa `ListBox2.Items.Add(F.Name);`

e No excluir:
Alterei essa linha `DeleteFile(ListBox2.Items[ListBox2.ItemIndex]);`
Para essa `DeleteFile(diretorio+'\'+ExtractFileName(ListBox2.Items[(ListBox2.Itemindex)]));`